# AppPool in IIS Express must run under Integrated Mode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, dotnetnuke, iis-express

I am using the IIS Express instead of the Visual Studio 2012 Development Server to install the DotNetNuke 7.0.04 because DotNetNuke 7 requires integrated mode and ASP.NET Development Server doesn't support Integrated Mode, however, the installation process throws the following exception:

AppPool in IIS must run under Integrated Mode

Is there any way to configure the IIS Express Integration Mode? Or any other solution to get over this problem.

Comment: Unless I'm really mistaken, integrated mode roughly means that all requests are processed through the .NET pipeline and this is exactly what happens with Cassini or IIS Express. Maybe you didnt configure  .NET Nuke correctly?

Comment: @tucaz, I just re-installed a fresh copy of the DNN 7.0.4, no special configurations are needed and still having the same problem.